# Most common nutrient deficiencies for athletes (runners)

Tags: supplement, deficiency, iron, iron-supplements

Runners in particular are sometimes at an elevated risk for iron deficiency / anemia. What are some of the other most common nutritional deficiencies for runners / athletes?

Answer (score -2):

You need to keep using protein (which is egg white), you need to keep your diet into fruit not fast foods (pizza).

There are some supplements which you can take to have balanced health, which you daily not inserting into your health system